# How to redict user to Payoneer for the payment for goods?

Tags: payment

Does Payoneer give possibility to redirect users to their site with giving settings in POST-inquiry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Payoneer currently not providing ways for sending users to a payment page via POST inquiries.
Having said that, we are working on new and innovative services and solutions that will enable such activity in the coming year.

Thank you,

```
Yaniv Chechik - CTO
```

Comment: I am having issues integrating the SDK into my App. I have posted an issue on the github repository, kindly check:
https://github.com/Armor-Payments/armor-payments-php/issues/5

Comment: Is there are any API now? where i can send payment to users?